# What does "To join in marriage by me" mean?

Tags: meaning

Right now I'm translating a marriage license and I'm not sure how to translate the phrase "To join in marriage by me".

Fuller context:

> I hereby certify that, in accordance with the above license, the persons herein mentioned were joined in marriage by me,

Does this mean the parties attended a ceremony?
Who is "me" in this context? What does he do for the couple?
(The document is signed by a magistrate)

Comment: To be confident, a little more context is probably needed. However it just sounds like "I (the magistrate) will officiate at the marriage".

Comment: A bit more context (e.g., a full sentence, or a description of the surrounding blanks and what's been filled in) might be helpful.

Comment: Full sentence here " I hereby certify that, in accordance with the above license, the persons herein mentioned were joined in marriage by me, in  XXXTownship, county of XXX, MICHIGAN...

Comment: OP's text is from [the Michigan marriage license as worded in 1894](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+persons+herein+mentioned+were+joined+in+marriage+by+me%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22the+persons+herein+mentioned+were+joined+in+marriage+by+me%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899). It was probably changed a *long* time ago, since by today's standards it's rather ungainly, to say the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's strange to me, so so it is to mighty Google Books:

["To join in marriage by me"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22To%20join%20in%20marriage%20by%20me%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22To%20join%20in%20marriage%20by%20me%22)
0 results

This is the expected clause:

> Kansas Brides - Book 2 - Page 358 Denise Hunter - 2004
>
> Dear Emily, I am so pleased and honored that you have agreed **to join
> me in marriage.**

Is that an official form or is it written by someone for the occasion?

Anyway, we need the entire context, as it could come as phrased by the person officiating, which would make it more understandable, as the commentators mentioned.

It could be in that case

*You two are **to join in marriage by me***

that is "beside me," indicating a position.

*You two are **to be joined in marriage by me***

would show the person being the agent.

> _

**OK, now that we have the real sentence**

*the persons herein mentioned were joined in marriage by me*

this is in past tense and in passive voice, showing the agent ("me").

It means roughly that

*"the persons mentioned in this document were married by me"*.

Is this easier to translate?

The direct meaning is:

*"the persons mentioned in this document were **/connected/linked/joined/ in marriage** by me"*

but that means "married."

Comment: I took it from an official US Marriage License and Certificate of Marriage.

Comment: Can you provide the full sentence, also perhaps the one leading to it?

Comment: Yes. Full sentence is "CERTIFICATE OF MARRIAGE Between .... and ...I hereby certify that, in accordance with the above license, the persons herein mentioned were joined in marriage by me, in XXXTownship, county of XXX, MICHIGAN, on the xx day of xxx A.D. 20xx, in the presence of  [Signature of Groom]  [Signature of Bride] [Signature of witness] [Name of witness] [Signature of Magistrate or Clergy] [Name of Magistrate or Clergy] [Post office Address of Magistrate or Clergy]

Comment: Updated at the end the answer. This is different from what you initially posted and is of course correct.

Comment: @Gonni Please update the question to give more of the full sentence. "joined in marriage" is very different in meaning from "were joined in marriage".

Answer (score 3):

As Joffan supposed in a comment, this statement is made by the officiant, and means

> The officiant married the couple.

The odd wording is used to change the emphasis.  First, the marriage contract is less important than the joining and joint future life, therefore the verb is replaced:

> The officiant joined the couple in marriage.

Also, the role of the officiant is rather unimportant compared to the vows taken by the bride and groom and (in a religious ceremony) the blessing of God.  And the identity of the officiant even less important.  Therefore passive voice is applied, which removes the officiant from being the subject of the sentence:

> The couple were joined in marriage by the officiant.

Since these words are affirmed by the officiant, first person is used, giving:

> The couple were joined in marriage by me.

which is scarcely different from the actual phrasing

> The persons named herein were joined in marriage by me.

Therefore, during translation, you want to express that

> The officiant affirms/certifies that he officiated at the marriage of the specified couple and knows it to be validly performed.

and phrase it in a way that, in the new language, emphasizes the importance of the couple rather than the officiant.

Comment: excellent answer @Ben Voigt